# Multiplicar filas de tabla dinámica y sumar columnas de total

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

El problema que tengo es que la primera fila si hace la función multiplicación perfecto, el problema reside que al agregar mas filas, cuando ingreso los valores no me hace la función de multiplicación, además de que deseo agregar un campo en el que tenga como resultado la suma de toda la columna total.

No se si tenga algún tipo de problema en el código de la función de multiplicar o en el de agregar otra fila, lo que si puede decir es que a pesar de que las siguientes filas no me hacen la función, al momento de guardarlas en mi base de datos, los valores ingresados se guardan porque los inicio en 0

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    //Variables
     var html = '<p /><div> <input type="TEXT" name="cantidad[]"    id="cantidad"   value=0 onChange="multiplicar();"/> <input type="TEXT" name="preuni[]"  id="preuni"  value=0 onChange="multiplicar();"/> <input type="TEXT" name="total[]"    id="total" value=0 onChange="multiplicar();"/> <a href="#" id="remove">X</a></div> ';

     var maxrows = 5;

     var x = 1;
     
    //agregar filas al form
    $("#add").click(function(e){
        $("#container").append(html);

    });

    //remover filas del form
    $("#container").on('click','#remove',function(e){

        $(this).parent('div').remove();

    });

    //populate values from the first row


});
</script>

<script>
function multiplicar(){
  m1 = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("preuni").value;
  r = m1*m2;
  document.getElementById("total").value = r;
}
</script>

    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="dynamicfields.php">
    <div id="container">
    cantidad: <input type="TEXT" name="cantidad[]"    id="cantidad"   value=0 onChange="multiplicar();"/> 
    precio unitario: <input type="TEXT" name="preuni[]"  id="preuni"  value=0 onChange="multiplicar();"/> 
    total: <input type="TEXT" name="total[]"    id="total" value=0 onChange="multiplicar();"/> 
    <a href="#" id="add"> Add More</a>
    </div>
    <p />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola, estás usando ids repetidos, primero tendrías que cambiar eso para que el código funcione correctamente.

Comment: Tú dices que por los ids no me está multiplicando las filas que agrego y por eso me multiplica la primera nada más?

Comment: Sí, porque siempre está guardando los mismos valores del principio, es decir, m1, m2 y r quedan con los valores de la primera línea; cada id debe ser único por documento, si agregas varias filas y modificas los valores de la primera, los recalcula y muestra sólo en la primera fila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te dijeron en los comentarios, no puedes duplicar ID, porque siempre toma solo el primero. Aparte, los atributos y valores HTML deben ser en minúsculas.

Entre los cambios realizados:

- Remplazar ID por clase y poner atributos en minúscula
- Eliminar eventos `onchange="..."` en etiquetas
- Al cargar el DOM se asignan los eventos, delegándolos a `document` porque es la única forma de aplicar también a elementos que se agregan posteriormente
- Funcionalidad que no te permite agregar líneas si se llegó al límite de `maxrows`
- En la función multiplicar se recibe el evento, de ahí se obtiene el campo que se modificó con `e.target` para encontrar el contenedor y, a partir de ahí, buscar los 3 campos necesarios para realizar el cálculo
- Agregué una función para calcular el total de todos los elementos y mostrarlo arriba del botón; se ejecuta cada que hay cambio en los *input* o cuando se elimina una fila

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //Variables
    var html = `
        <p>
            Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" class="cantidad" value="0"> 
            Precio unitario: <input type="text" name="preuni[]" class="preuni" value="0"> 
            Total: <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" value="0" readonly> 
            <a href="#" class="remove">X</a>
        </p>
    `;
    var maxrows = 5;
    var x = 1;
    // Asignar evento a cantidad y precio unitario
    $(document).on("change", ".cantidad", multiplicar);
    $(document).on("change", ".preuni", multiplicar);

    //agregar filas al form
    $("#add").click(function(e) {
        // Evitar que se agreguen más filas que las especificadas en maxrows
        if(x < maxrows) {
            $("#container").append(html);
            x ++;
        }
    });

    //remover filas del form
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
        $(this).parent('p').remove();
        x --;
        calcularTotal();
    });
});

function multiplicar(e) {
    // Obtener contenedor desde el elemento que cambió
    let p = $(e.target).closest('p');
    // Usar .find() para obtener cantidad, precio y total
    let m1 = parseFloat($(p).find(".cantidad").val()) || 0;
    let m2 = parseFloat($(p).find(".preuni").val()) || 0;
    // Asignar cálculo al campo total
    $(p).find(".total").val(m1 * m2);
    calcularTotal();
}

function calcularTotal() {
    // Inicializar total
    let total = 0;
    // Recorrer totales para sumar
    $.each($('.total'), (index, item) => total += parseInt($(item).val()) || 0);
    // Mostrar total
    $('#gran-total').text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="dynamicfields.php">
    <div id="container">
        <p>
            Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" class="cantidad" value="0"> 
            Precio unitario: <input type="text" name="preuni[]" class="preuni" value="0"> 
            Total: <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" value="0" readonly> 
            <a href="#" id="add">Add More</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>Total: $<span id="gran-total">0</span></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Perfecto realmente me funciono bastante, disculpa la molestia, pero si yo desearia sumar toda la columna y colocar ese resultado en campo, como tendria que hacer, estaría muy agradecido si me pudieras ayudar con eso tambien. Buenas tardes.

Comment: Listo, revisa la actualización

Comment: Buenas noches estuve modificando bastante el codigo con el que me ayudaste pero ahora me falta un solo detalle porque donde colocaste total en dolares, yo lo cambie a subtotal, para luego eso multiplicarlo por el iva que yo lo coloco o lo dejo en 0 y que al hacer la cuenta de subtotal con el iva, ahi si me de el resultado total con iva en dolares por ejemplo

Comment: Se entiende mas o menos la idea de lo que quiero hacer?